# How to extract time from DateTime object in php?

Tags: php

I am working on a **php code** as shown below in which I want to extract **time** from **DateTime object**.

Here is the **php code**:

```
$timestamp = new \DateTime($episode->air_date, new \DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));

$new_timestamp = clone $timestamp;

print_r($new_timestamp); // Line A
```

**Line A above prints:**

```
DateTime Object ( [date] => 2019-11-14 23:00:00.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => America/New_York )
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what **php code** I need to add so that it extracts **time (hr and mins only)** from **DateTime object**.

In the php code above, I have added Line A for debugging purpose.

Comment: You can use "format" take a look here : https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Comment: @Inazo that's an answer. You're more than welcome to post it as such and reap the benefits :)

Comment: @Inazo that *was* an answer...

Answer (score 3):

use `format` to get any format of your [choosing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

```php
$timestamp = new DateTime();
$new_timestamp = clone $timestamp;
print_r($new_timestamp->format('H:i:s')); // 16:30:52
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `DateTime::format` method, as answered by Gavin. Or, if you're more familiar with `strftime`'s format specifiers, or just need its generally-better locale-sensitivity, you can use it instead:

```
php > $timestamp = new DateTime();
php > print_r(strftime('%T', $timestamp->getTimestamp()));
16:38:29
```